# merge every two equal elements into another one

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

How to merge every two equal elements in the list into one element and the merge process is specified by lambda function.

For example if I have a list like this

["a","a","b","b"]

And the merge process is `{it.repeat(2)}`

it should be like this:

["aa","bb"]

but if the list is like this:

["a","a","a"]

It should be converted to

["aa","a"]

Another example is :

["a","b","a","b"]

will be

["a", "b","a","b"]

I tried `zipWithNext()` but I can't figure out what to do next especially when there is more than two repeat of the same letter.

How to implement like this in Kotlin using **functional programming** way of Kotlin.

Comment: What happens for `a, b, a, b`? It just stays `a, b, a, b`? I have a doubt that it's unlikely that there is a built-in operator that creates a varying number of elements by a predicate. Why not use a for loop?

Comment: It will be the same `a, b, a, b` because no equal adjacent is found.

Comment: Because the task is preferably to be written in functional style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes the very **inefficient** but, **desired** solution. As requested, I've used `functional programming` as much as possible. Hope you'll like it. But, it would be very easy if you use `loop` or `regular expression` to solve this problem.
In this question functional style is not needed.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = listOf("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
    //val list = listOf("a", "a", "a", "b", "a")
    var temp = false
    val result = list.zipWithNext().map {
        if (temp) {
            temp = false
            null
        } else {
            if (it.first == it.second) {
                temp = true
                it.first + it.second
            } else {
                it.first
            }
        }
    }.filter { !it.isNullOrBlank() }.toMutableList()
    if (!temp) {
        result.add(list.last())
    }

    print(result)
}
```